# Oracle RCU error unable to connect to DB

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence

Am new to Oracle and trying to install BI. My database is on my local system. While am installing RCU unable to connect the database.

I have Oracle 12C

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this out. Edited the hosts file and rebooted.
Checked from command line and was working RCU started installing.